# How to start a microsoft flow in SPO Classic Experience?

Tags: sharepoint-online, navigation, microsoft-flow

sorry I'm new to SharePoint, not really familar with environment yet.

I read [this article from microsoft support on how to create a flow in SPO](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Create-a-flow-for-a-list-or-library-in-SharePoint-Online-A9C3E03B-0654-46AF-A254-20252E580D01). However, the problem is that my interface is totally differnt from what they had and I can't find the "flow" function to start with. My workflow is totally different from the article. The workflow I had is the [build-in workflow](http://Introduction-to-SharePoint-workflow-07982276-54e8-4e17-8699-5056eff4d9e3) provided by SPO.

Hope somebody could help me how to  navigate or tell me what did I missed.

This is what they showed.[image: List Function]

This is what I had.[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

SharePoint online sites within office 365 have got two versions I would say:

1. Classic experience
2. Modern experience (Latest)

The one you are seeing in the blog is from Modern experience. Classic lists/libraries do not have option of flows internally. You need to change it to modern experience. Process for switching to modern experience is:

-> Click on the gear on top right.

-> Select site contents.

-> Go to the settings of your list/library.

-> From the settings option select **Advanced settings**.

-> Scroll down, till you see "**List experience**", now select "New Experience" and click OK.

Now you will be able to see the flow option within your list/library.