# Flow only Available for Modern Experience

Tags: sharepoint-online, modern-experience, flow, classic-experience

I used to have one Document Library in classic Experience ánd Flow was not available. (that's why I thought it was not included in our purchase )

I know created a new Document Library on the same SharePoint and Flow is avaiable and I can create flows.

Anyone know why its not there for the classic Experience.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's by design that Classic lists/libraries do not have option of flows internally. You need to change it to modern experience. Starting a flow from Flow Launch Panel is is only available on all modern SharePoint lists and libraries currently.

Here are some similar post:

https://powerusers.microsoft.com/t5/Building-Flows/Manually-Run-a-Flow-using-Classic-Experience/td-p/96998

[How to start a microsoft flow in SPO Classic Experience?](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/228839/how-to-start-a-microsoft-flow-in-spo-classic-experience)

Answer (score 3):

You can use Flow with classic, you just can't do it from the command bar. You can go into Flow directly and work with your classic sites/libraries from there.